# Where to put Error Alert in my JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Where I need to place `Error Alert code` in this JavaScript and if it is of any use in such JavaScript.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get("ImagePreview?b_id=<%=id%>", function (responseJson) {
            var $select = $("<div>").addClass("galleria").appendTo($("#imgas"));
            $.each(responseJson, function (index, item) {
                $("<img />").attr("src", item).appendTo($select);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: For compatibility use `$("<div/>")` with a `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Put an alert every odd line like `alert("A")`, `alert("B")` etc
- Refresh the page
- Remove every alert from your code and keep the one you like best

P.S: if you want to test the actual `responseJson` than `alert` is a **bad idea**.
Use `console.dir(responseJson);` inside your AJAX function.